# Simple Login Form using node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express

I started to learn nodejs and installed express with their documentation. Now on the process, i want to create a login form and on clicking log-in i want it to pass to **check** route to check the credentials.

I am not posting the full code here. Just the  part of it.

```
var routes = require('./routes/index'); //default with express
var users = require('./routes/users'); //default with express
var login = require('./routes/login'); //created by me
var check = require('./routes/check'); //created by me.
```

**Update 2**

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/check', check);
```

The login route is working fine and i am getting the output. When i  click  login, it enters the route

```
http://localhost:3000/check
```

and throws 404  not found.

Whereas if i directly enter the url in my browser i am getting the output in the browser.

**check.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

**updating check.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**login.jade**

```
extends layout
  block content
    div(class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4")
    h1 User Login
    form(name="login", action="/check", method="post")
      div(class="form-group")
        input(type="text", name="user" class="form-control")
      div(class="form-group")
        input(type="password", name="pass" class="form-control")
      div(class="form-group")
        input(type="submit", value="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control")
```

I am also looking for basic documentation to create a node.js application, that is not complicated as well and easy to understand for a noob.

Update 1: Error while clicking with login button

```
Error: Not Found
    at app.use.res.render.message (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/app.js:38:13)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:603:15
    at next (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:246:14)
    at Function.proto.handle (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:3)
    at router (/home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:35:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 2**

the router has to be applied as middleware via app.use() :

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});

app.use('/check', router);

then a POST Request on Path "/check" would be handeled by your router.
```

if you are not doing this provide the routing directly via app.post() like this

```
app.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource'); 
});
```

**EDIT**:

action="/check" is enough ;)

But you are still missing the Fact that the form sends an POST to the Route "/check" and your express Router is listeing to a GET request on Route "/"

**ORIGINAL**:

I think u are using the action attribute of the form Tag wrong:
it should be

```
action="http://www.yourDomain.com/check"
```

maybe i am wrong and

```
action="/check"
```

is enough,

but also you are listening for an GET Request and the form is sending a POST on submit.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

Also the route you are listeing to is "/" and schould be "/check"
my approach would be:

**check.js**

```
router.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

**login.jade**

```
extends layout
block content
 div(class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-offset-4")
 h1 User Login
 form(name="login", action="http://www.yourDomain.com/check", method="post")
  div(class="form-group")
    input(type="text", name="user" class="form-control")
  div(class="form-group")
    input(type="password", name="pass" class="form-control")
  div(class="form-group")
    input(type="submit", value="login" class="btn btn-warning form-control")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You definitely don't need to include the full domain name in a form action; if it's on the same domain then `/check` would be relative to that domain. The issue is the GET v. POST.

Comment: Nope. Its not working change to full domain or using POST too. I tested it even before i posted it.

Comment: i edited it again, the problem in my opinion is that u are listeing for a GET Request to "/" in express and the form is sending a POST to "/check".

Comment: Added an update of error output shown in the screen while clicking login button

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene Don't add an image, add the text.

Comment: I have updated my check.js file and posted it . Still no luck

Comment: are you adding that router to a middleware via app.use?

if not you could directly use app.post() instead of router.post()

i post it as edit 2 above, maybe thats it

Comment: /home/alaksandar/Desktop/Untitled Folder/myapp/routes/check.js:5
    app.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
    ^
ReferenceError: app is not defined

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In app.js use

`app.use('/check',check)`

And in check.js use

```
 router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

And be sure you are exporting this function using module.exports

**old**

In your check.js file you need to use

```
router.post('/check', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

Instead of

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

Comment: Please check my update. I already did this and posted with not luck.

Comment: Added update 2 which is the same as per your advise.

Comment: dont use '/check' inside the router.post in check.js , use '/' only

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But earlier it didnt work. No idea why it was not working earlier.

Comment: mayb because of app.get  instead of app.post?

Comment: i thought about it. It works for app.get also. Do i need to restart node.js everytime i change the code

Comment: Ya , i use nodemon for automatic restart.Try it